# positive ground / neg. ground

Tags: electrical

With a/c current in a home rather than a vehicle, I don't think one would ever get a positive ground. Electricity always flow from the positive to the negative from what I have been learning about a/c voltage.

If a vehicle's battery is connected by a positive ground, does it mean that the electricity is flowing from neg. to positive rather than positive to negative ?

Comment: By definition, electricity always flows from positive to negative.  Also, note that in alternating current, the concept of "hot" and "ground" aren't the same as in a direct current system like a car.  Sound like your questions are more "fundamentals of electricity" rather than "Motor Vehicle Maintenance".

Comment: Hi there, this question sounds like you're looking for introduction to electronic theory. Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair is for questions directly relating to how vehicles work and the maintenanc thereof. Your question is more about electronics. You might try searching for answers over on [Electronics.SE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/) or performing some [google searches.](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+does+a+car+battery+work)

Comment: It's definitely related to automotive electronics, though. I used to encounter this all the time, particularly with automatic interior light door switches. It was confusing. (12V DC+ though.)

Comment: I hope I am doing this right....ducatikiller.. I appreciate the response and I will think on it .   Frank O'Donnell

Answer (score 1):

With a DC battery, electricity actually flows from the negative (where the electrons are repelled) to the positive (where the electrons are attracted) side of the battery. It doesn't matter which grounding method you use (positive or negative ground), the electricity will still flow the same direction.

On the [Illinois Education website](https://van.physics.illinois.edu/qa/listing.php?id=583) the question of electricity flow is answered thus:

> Electrons are negatively charged, and so are attracted to the positive end of a battery and repelled by the negative end. So when the battery is hooked up to something that lets the electrons flow through it, they flow from negative to positive.

For the most part vehicles use a negative ground (earth). Manufacturers quit using a positive ground (how things started in the automobile industry) because with this setup, [galvanic corrosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galvanic_corrosion) occurs. Some vehicle still use a positive ground, but they are far and few between.

You may also find more information [in this Q/A](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/1934/what-are-the-tradeoffs-for-positive-vs-negative-ground) which will help answer your question.

Comment: Be careful with [Current flow vs electron flow](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/17109/why-is-the-charge-naming-convention-wrong).  Its true that on a particle level "electrons" flow from negative to positive, but "Electricity" or current is said to flow from positive to negative.