# Starting a diesel tractor

Tags: electrical, starting, diesel, jump-start, tractor

I have a diesel tractor with a generator. After sitting for a long period the battery was low so I used a portable jumper battery but mistakenly hooked up the cables in reverse. This caused smoke to come from the positive terminal hookup and fried the jumper battery which I replaced. I recharged the battery on the tractor and it turns over very well but the engine won't start.

Could I have damaged the electrical system in the tractor? If so what would be the fix? Could the electrical system be reversed polarity. This tractor always started up when battery was charged. The fuse on the dash appears to be OK The tractor is a 1955 INTERNATIONAL 504 DIESEL.

Comment: Can we assume that the magic smoke started the instant you touched battery cables, and that you did NOT push the starter button?

Comment: Define "sitting for a long period"

Comment: Why would a bad electrical system cause a diesel to not start?  Don't these tractors have mechanical fuel pumps, with mechanical control linkages?  There aren't any electrons anywhere in that chain, unless there is a fuel shut off solenoid stuck closed somewhere...

Comment: @zipzit, well, no starter for one right?  And do tractors not have glow plugs for starting (honestly have no idea)?

Comment: Related: http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/1934/12030, interesting if not helpful.

Comment: @JPhi1618  Sorry. I was responding to the phrases `it turns over very well but the engine won't start. Could I have damaged the electrical system in the tractor?`  Given that the starter `turns over very well`, there really isn't much else that is electrical in that conversation.  Glow plugs is a possible.  Solenoid / electronic controls of the fuel pump is another... but for a tractor? I really doubt it.  I would think the design guys are totally focused on simple and robust.

Comment: The only shut off on this should be manual, I'd bet. They didn't put much in the way of electronic *anything* on diesel tractors this old. My bet is the fuel system is clogged and is not wanting to flow anything. You could use starter fluid in the intake tract to see if it will fire over, but that will only tell you the internals of the engine are doing good. I don't think your battery mishap had anything to do with the no-start situation.

Comment: Echoing what @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 said, if the engine is runnable at all (adequate compassion, injectors and pump work) then it should run if you give it fuel and air – and crank it fast enough. Starting fluid will rule out the fuel system, so that is worth a try – it will tell you that the engine can run, if it gets fuel. I'd put my money on bad fuel or something stopping fuel delivery.

Comment: AIR trapped in injector lines and the pump.  After setting you can get air in and the pump can not over come this.  You need to bleed the lines at the injectors till fuel comes out.

Answer (score 3):

Just wanted to combine a number of the comments into an answer:

Older diesel tractors really didn't have much in the way of electrics for the engine, aside from the starter, and you have already told us the engine turns over nicely so the basic assumption is that the electrics are okay.

Also, as zipzit commented, if the smoke came as you touched the cables to the battery, before you actually tried to start the tractor, it is unlikely you did any damage beyond the battery itself.

So the most likely cause is simple clogged fuel lines or contaminated fuel from sitting for a long time without being run. So test using starter fluid in the intake, and if it runs that should confirm this diagnosis.